# Return random element from array excluding elements from subarray

Tags: algorithm, random

Basically, I need something like this:

```
f(a[], b[]) = random element from a[] which is not in b[]
```

Idea I have is this one:

```
while true:
   e = element_from_uniform(a[])
   if e not in b[]: return e
```

Problem is, I want this function to be fast, since it will be calculating many many times (every frame on multiple objects). I know that since we are choosing from uniform distribution, eventually some element from `a[]` will pop up that isn't in `b[]`.

Any ideas? Oh, if it helps, `a[].length` is always 6 and `b[]` is always some subset of `a[]` and `b.length < a.length`.

**EDIT:**

I want this to be done without allocating any of new memory, only with pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For faster algorithm you need to think about each cost of your implementation.

First, if `b` is a subset of `a`, and if you keep `b` sorted, you can search for any element using Binary Search `O = lg n`. Pickup for a random elment, if you are using al Linear Congruent generator of the form `x_{n+1} = x_{n} % M + b`, so pickup a random element is `O(1)`

So, with this approach you can returning in a `lg n`, but keep `b` orderer in the worst case may cost you `m lg m` (where `m` = `|b|`) with Mergesort or Quicksort.

Comment: Since the length of `a` is always `6` and the length of `b` less than the length of `a` I'm not sure that binary search is, in practice, going to provide any advantage at all.

Comment: Accepting because of Linear Congruent Generator! :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!, I think that binary search is pretty good because `lgn` is cute, no only on this case, and is important to mention it as improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create $a \setminus b$. In Python there is for example the function [difference()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). Then you can choose an element from $s\setminus b$ randomly...

Comment: I don't want to allocate any of new memory. Everything has to be done with pointers, I should have probably said this in question :)